# Proxying WebSocket connections and ephemeral port exhaustion

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I'm designing an application that make will use of WebSocket to notify visitors quickly when changes occur. I'm planning to proxy the connections with Nginx, so they can share the same address as the regular HTTP portion. One thing I'm concerned about is the exhaustion of ephemeral ports. In the past, I have noticed problems when the number of connections between Nginx and the Node backend exceeds 25000. My question is, would the following config increases the limit to 100K?

```
upstream backends {
    server 127.0.0.1:5000;
    server 127.0.0.2:5000;
    server 127.0.0.3:5000;
    server 127.0.0.4:5000;
}
```

The limit on open files will need to be raised accordingly, of course.

Assuming the technique works, can it be used with external servers? How hard is it to assign a range of IP addresses to an interface? Networking is not my forte...

Comment: For a single server:port combo, the theoretical upper limit of connections should be the number of possible client-ip:client-port combos, which is a lot. You should never even come close to exhausting your ephemeral ports. Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: @greim - I think the question relates to the ephemeral ports between the local Nginx proxy and the local websocket service - so the client-ip is always the same. This would give you a hard upper limit of ~65K connections (port number limitations apply here) divided by two (one port for the proxy client and one for service)... but this is just a hypothesis, I'm waiting for someone more knowledgeable to answer.

Comment: Yes @Myst It's exactly the case I'm dealing with. Haven't figured out a good way yet.

Comment: @starshinewang - did you consider using a Unix socket instead of TCP/IP. Some limitations, such as port numbers, might be avoided using a local Unix socket that doesn't really use ports to identify the service...?

Comment: Confirmed that proxy_bind can help solve the issue!

Answer (score 2):

Please try [proxy_bind](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_bind) . It

> Makes outgoing connections to a proxied server originate from the
>   specified local IP address. Parameter value can contain variables
>   (1.3.12).

So if our nginx proxy server can have several IP addresses your problem can be resolved. e.g.

```
location / {
   ...
   proxy_bind $picked_ip;
   proxy_pass http://backends;
}
```

The variable `$picked_ip` can be computed by a rewrite handler which runs before `proxy_pass` does.